# How to turn off insearch in VIM?

Tags: vim

everybody. This afternoon I've read through VIM's tutorial.
But there is a question left, I've tried google and search on stackflow, no relevant answers.

I know `:set hls` is to open highlight search and insearch function.
And I also know, I can use `:set nohls` to turn off highlight search
But when I try to use `:set nois` or `:set noinsearch`
'Whoops!' comes

Could anyone who passed by can told me how to turn off insearch?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean `incsearch`?

Comment: @romainl, is that called incsearch? I only know its abbreviation name is, and I think it's insearch. what does 'inc' mean here?

Comment: There's no option called `insearch`: the closer is `incsearch` which can be shortened to `is`. Do `:set is` to turn it on, do `:set nois` to turn it off, do `:set is!` to toggle its state. Learn to use `:help`, it's far more useful than Google or StackOverflow: `:help 'nois'`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can toggle a setting with a bang!

```
:set is!
```

Or if you aren't sure of the current status, prefix with `no`:

```
:set nois
```

These should work for you. If not, you have something with your setup or vim. Also note that the long form of the setting is spelled `incsearch` with a `c`.